# Сменить цвет текста в alert

Tags: javascript, html, цвета, alert

html:

```
      <!DOCTYPE html>
      <html>
      <head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/styles.css">
</head>
<body>
<form id = "mainForm">
    <div id = "div1">
       <input type="text" name="input-1" id = "input1" value="" size="10px">         
       <input type="text" name="input-2" id = "input2" value="" size="10px"> 
       <input type="text" name="input-3" id = "input3" value="" size="10px"> 
       <input type="text" name="input-4" id = "input4" value="" size="10px">

       <select id="listColor">
                         <option value="green">
                                Зеленый
                            </option>
                            <option value="red">
                                Красный
                            </option>
                            <option value="blue">
                                Синий
                            </option>
                            <option value="yellow">
                                Желтый    
                            </option>
        </select>
      </div>

      <div id  = "div2">
      <input type="reset" name="Очистка формы"></td>       
      <button id = "showButton" >Отобразить данные</button>
      <button id = "insertButton">Вставка текстового поля</button>
      </div>

</form>

<script src="../js/index.controller.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body> 
</html>
```

JS:

```
           function showData(event){
           event.preventDefault();

           var formElements = document.getElementById('mainForm');
           if(formElements.input1.value === '' || formElements.input2.value === '' || formElements.input3.value ==='' || formElements.input4.value ==='')
    {
         alert('Заполните все поля');

         highlightFileds();
    }
    else {
        var listColor = document.getElementById('listColor');

        if(listColor.value === 'green')
        {
        <!--Цвет текста в алерт зеленый-->    
        alert(formElements.input1.value +"\n" + formElements.input2.value + "\n" + formElements.input3.value + "\n" + formElements.input4.value+ "\n");
        }

        if(listColor.value === 'red')
        {
        <!--Цвет текста в алерт красный-->    
        alert(formElements.input1.value +"\n" + formElements.input2.value + "\n" + formElements.input3.value + "\n" + formElements.input4.value+ "\n");
        }

        if(listColor.value === 'blue')
        {
        <!--Цвет текста в алерт синий-->    
        alert(formElements.input1.value +"\n" + formElements.input2.value + "\n" + formElements.input3.value + "\n" + formElements.input4.value+ "\n");
        }

        if(listColor.value === 'yellow')
        {
        <!--Цвет текста в алерт желтый-->    
        alert(formElements.input1.value +"\n" + formElements.input2.value +  "\n" + formElements.input3.value + "\n" + formElements.input4.value+ "\n");
        }
    }

}
```

Как изменить текст выводимого текста в alert?

Comment: [решение вашей проблемы](http://age-dragon.com/scripts/alert.html)

Comment: решить задачу необходимо не использую jquery